Prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2})^{x^2}$ does not exist
Which sequences should one choose to effectively prove that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\left(\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^{x^2}$$ does not exist? Obviously, we deal with
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}x^2*ln\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$
I tried to substitute $x=y=\frac{1}{n}$ and $x=\frac{1}{n}$, $y=\frac{1}{n^2}$ ($n$ approaches infinity), but in both cases $x^2$ seems to drag the whole thing to zero?
Thanks!

Let $f(x,y)=\left(\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)^{x^2}$.
We have $f(x,0)=0$ for every $x\neq 0$, so if the limit exists it must be equal to $0$.
But along the line $y=x$ we get $f(x,y)=f(x,x)=\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+x^2}\right)^{x^2}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2}$, which tends to $1$ when $x\to 0$. This means the limit does not exist.
In terms of sequences you could consider $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left(\dfrac{1}{n},0\right)$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left(\dfrac{1}{n},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

You do not need to look at the $\ln$ of the function you are taking the limit of.  If the limit does exist, say it equals $L$, then for any pair of sequences $x_n, y_n \to 0$ we need $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = L$. You are right that to prove the limit does not exist, it suffices to find either a pair of sequences $x_n,y_n$ for which $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n,y_n)$ does not exist, or two pairs of sequences that show that show that $L$ has to be two different values. (Both lead to contradictions.) This is the standard way to prove the limit does not exist, so you're on the right track.
In your case, as @Julio Puerta's answer shows, taking for instance as a first pair $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $y_n = 0$ and as a second pair $x_n = y_n = \frac{1}{n}$ indeed gives you that, if the limit exists, it must be two values and therefore we have a contradiction: the limit does not exist.
